# Starting and stopping a numerical diffusion equation

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, diffusion

I am asked to solve the following problem numerically with Python with one of Euler methods:

> Calculate the diffusion of particles with a diffusion constant $D=0.025$ on a surface ($24\times24$ grid, $2\times2$ mm) with absorbing boundary conditions. As a start value we drop a substance in the middle of the surface, you can simulate this  with a number of particles $n_{ij}(t)=N \,{\rm mol}$ in the middle 4 cells (we have to calculate this for N=10, 100, 10000 etc.) and to stop the program when there are less than 0.01 mol particles on the surface.

I am aware of the Euler method and there are enough examples around on how to solve the heat equation numerically, but I am facing problem in implementing the initial conditions to this problem and how to stop the program. Any hints or tips on how to implement the code would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about physics; it is a question about coding.  You could try [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-physics) as a more appropriate place.  That site is "for questions and answers about computational methods used in technical disciplines."

Comment: Also, it is not at all clear what you're asking.  If you do ask on scicomp.SE, please include much more specific questions.  As it stands, it looks like you're asking people to just write the code for you.

Comment: I am asking on how to set the initial conditions and how to stop the code. I think this is pretty clear.

Comment: Well, maybe it's clear that you're asking questions that sound *extremely* broad.  There's no way to answer those without an extensive and detailed understanding of your code — at least not with any more detail than "initialize your variables" and "use an `if` statement to test how many particles are on the surface, then exit the loop".  Are you using C, Fortran, Python, Scala, Lisp, Matlab, Mathematica???  Are you using particular libraries???  You don't have to argue with me.  Just be more specific with exactly what you're confused about when you ask the question in a more appropriate place.

Comment: -1 Not clear what your difficulty is. Your middle paragraph describes the initial conditions and your criterion for stopping the program. Why are these difficult to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to model the diffusion of a droplet into a larger domain, the initial conditions are rather straight-forward: everywhere in the domain has 0 concentration (representing no droplet), except a point in the middle (where the drop is placed). Since your grid has an even number if cells, then the middle is a $2\times2$ block, so you need to put $N/4$ as the concentration there.

In Python, assuming you're using numpy (imported as np), this would be,

```
n=np.zeros((24,24), dtype=np.float)
n[12:14,12:14]=N/4
```

Where the 14 is needed as the upper bound because of Python's semantics.
More complicated initial conditions (e.g., two droplets, existing background, etc) would benefit from a double loop over the whole domain, but this is simple enough to not do for this problem.

The stopping condition is effectively when the droplet has diffused off the domain, represented by finding the total concentration to be less than some value. This could be implemented as a simple sum over the whole domain:

```
if np.sum(n)<threshold: break
```

Or it could be implemented as $N$ minus the total concentration removed from the domain, which is probably more complicated to implement than a simple sum, but YMMV. (Another alternative would be to use the *average* concentration per cell vs some threshold, but that's not what the problem states).